# Access to the Server

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v, windows-server

Suddenly, I'm unable to access my Windows Server 2016 remotely, nor ping it.
It is a Hyper-V virtual machine and I can access it from the host server.

- RDP is enabled
- I have tried to disable the firewall

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: What changed at the servers?  Did you change the IP addressing of the servers?  There is not much description above.

Comment: I don't think anything changed. I still can access it from the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much I can tell you from the provided info, but I would:

- Make sure you are in the same local network that the server is in
- If the server has a public IP address, make sure it has internet access
- Make sure DHCP hasn't changed either the local or public IP address and that you are trying to connect to the correct IP
- If you are connecting to a hostname, make sure that the DNS can find the IP by doing an `nslookup hostname` from the Command Line

Comment: The server has static IP, and it is within the network, also my RDP client. I already use IP to connect not DNS. I don't think anything changed. I still can access it from the host machine.

Comment: Are you connecting to a local IP?

Comment: Yes, both the server and my pc connected to the same local network.

Comment: Then check if the server settings in Hyper-V have a bridged network connection.